# What Am I doing wrong with this CSS?

Tags: css

I'm working on a page and I have the content placed in a wrapper on my stylesheet. However the background for the wrapper is not showing up behind the content and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code snippet.

```
#wrapper {
  width: 850px;
  margin-top: -44px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-image: url('http://www.website.com/tumblr/images/contentbg_grey.png') repeat-y center;
  border: dashed thin blue;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
background-image: url('http://www.website.com/tumblr/images/contentbg_grey.png') repeat-y center;
```

Should be:

```
background: url('http://www.website.com/tumblr/images/contentbg_grey.png') repeat-y center center;
```

Remove the "-image" if you're using the shorthand

Answer (score 0):

there is no image for this url.
Check your image. Css code seems right. Just change your background-image to background.
http://www.website.com/tumblr/images/contentbg_grey.png

To test:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#wrapper {
                width: 850px;
                min-width: 850px;
                min-height: 400px;
                margin-top: -44px;
                padding:15px;
                background: url('http://www.website.com/img/logo.png') repeat-y center;
                border: dashed thin blue;
                position:         relative;
                text-align:center;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```